# React Router v3 per flow bundle splitting

Tags: reactjs, split, webpack, react-router, bundle

Is there a way with what is available on React Roter v3 API to make per-flow bundle split? From documentation, and examples from the internet, there's a way to split, but it's **per-component**, using [PlainRoute](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#plainroute) with [getChildRoutes](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#getchildroutespartialnextstate-callback), [getComponent](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback) etc. Using it with `System.imports` I get splited sub-bundle for every Route separately.

What I tried was something like this, and I got `0.js, 1.js ... 9.js` chunks in the Network tab of dev-tools.

```
getChildRoutes(_, fetchComponents) {
    Promise.all([
        System.import('./pages/page1.jsx'),
        System.import('./pages/page2.jsx'),
        ...
        System.import('./pages/page10.jsx')
    ])
    .then(([page1, page2... page10]) => {
        fetchComponents(null, [
            {path: '...', indexRoute: {component: page1}},
            {path: '...', component: page2},
            ...
            {path: '...', component: page10}
        ])
    })
}
```

So is it possible with a structure like this two have only 3 chunks (sub-bundles)?

```
<Router ...>
 {/*flow 1*/}
  <Rote component...>
    <Route path... component... />
    <Route component>
      <IndexRoute .../>
      <Route path ... component... />
      <Route path ... component... />
      <Route path ... component... />
      ...
    </Route>
  </Route>

 {/*flow 2*/}
  <Route>
    ...
  </Route>

 {/*flow 3*/}
  <Route />
</Router>
```

If it's not possible to do it with React Router, I'd appreciate any hints how to do this properly with Webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is!

Here is how I did it in my project:

Inside your router.js file if you are using plain routes :

```
const componentRoutes = {
  path: '/',
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'routeA',
      getChildRoutes (partialNextState, callback) {
        System.import('./aRoutes')
          .then(module => callback(null, module.default))
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'routeB',
      getChildRoutes (partialNextState, callback) {
        System.import('./bRoutes')
          .then(module => callback(null, module.default))
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'routeC',
      getChildRoutes (partialNextState, callback) {
        System.import('./cRoutes')
          .then(module => callback(null, module.default))
      }
    },
  ]
}
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={componentRoutes} />
  )
}

export default Routes
```

Inside aRoutes.js:

```
import aDashboard from './containers/aDashboard'
import SomePage from './containers/SomePage'
const aRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'aDashboard',
    component: aDashboard
  },
  {
    path: 'somePage',
    component: SomePage
  }
]

export default aRoutes
```

Inside bRoutes.js:

```
import bDashboard from './containers/bDashboard'
import SomePageB from './containers/SomePageB'

const bRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'bDashboard',
    component: bDashboard
  },
  {
    path: 'somePageB',
    component: SomePageB
  }
]

export default bRoutes
```

Inside cRoutes.js:

```
import cDashboard from './containers/cDashboard'
import SomePageC from './containers/SomePagec'

const cRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'cDashboard',
    component: cDashboard
  },
  {
    path: 'somePageC',
    component: SomePageC
  }
]

export default cRoutes
```

So for your case I would have 3 "route" files that you use 3 System.import statements to pull in their childRoutes. You can put as many components as you want into each of the route files but you will only have 3 bundles because you only have 3 System.import calls. This way you can split your bundle into only three files and not per component. Hope this helps

Comment: That helped a lot!

Comment: I have a problem now: If I have 3 chunks like that, for the first flow (`path: 'app'`, in your example) `0.js` is fetched, for the second: `0.js` and `1.js`, for the third one `0.js`, `1.js` and `2.js`. These flows are 100% independent, and it doesn't matter the order: the last one always fetches all the chunks.

Comment: Hey, sorry if my answer wasn't clear. I updated the answer to hopefully solve you're problem. If that doesn't work post the code you are using and I'll try to figure out why it's getting all the chunks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581981/the-last-route-fetches-all-the-chunks-with-code-split-with-webpack-2-and-react-r I left more details here. I suppose there might be something wrong in shared components between flows.

Comment: Did you try creating your router using only plain routes? That seems to be the only difference. I don't seem to have the same issue in my project